# Accessing a dictionary value with variable as a key: Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm trying to generate a random element for a dictionary and then return both the key and the value so that I can manipulate both.

I'm coming from a Python background and I think that is preventing me from coming up with a solution:

```
myDict = ["key1" : 200.0, "key2" : 180.0]

let random_key = myDict.randomElement()?.key
let random_value = myDict[random_key]
```

I get an error message which states:

> Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Double]' with an index of type 'String?'

Answer (score 2):

Almost, you want a random element of all keys so it's

```
let myDict = ["key1" : 200.0, "key2" : 180.0]

let randomKey = myDict.keys.randomElement()!
let randomValue = myDict[randomKey]!
```

In Swift variable names are *lowerCamelCased* and force unwrapping of both expressions is safe because definitely all keys and values exist.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Still learning this stuff and I appreciate you helping me with conventions as well.

Answer (score 1):

`randomElement()` returns an *optional* which is `nil` if the collection (in your case, the dictionary) is empty. Then `random_key` is obtained via “optional chaining” and that makes it an optional as well.

If you know that the dictionary is not empty then you can force-unwrap:

```
let myDict = ["key1" : 200.0, "key2" : 180.0]
let random_key = myDict.randomElement()!.key
let random_value = myDict[random_key]
```

Actually you can avoid the dictionary look-up because `randomElement()` returns a dictionary element, which is a key/value pair:

```
let myDict = ["key1" : 200.0, "key2" : 180.0]
let randomElement = myDict.randomElement()!
let randomKey = randomElement.key
let randomValue = randomElement.value
```

If the dictionary is possibly empty then use optional binding:

```
let myDict = ["key1" : 200.0, "key2" : 180.0]
if let randomElement = myDict.randomElement() {
    let randomKey = randomElement.key
    let randomValue = randomElement.value
    // ...
} else {
    // Dictionary is empty
}
```

Comment: Thank you for unpacking all of that for me. It’s good practice to write dealing with contingencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way. `error` for `optional`

```
let random_key = myDict.randomElement()?.key
//print(random_key) //option output
if let _random_key = random_key{
  let random_value = myDict[_random_key]
  print(random_value ?? 0)
}
```

`myDict.randomElement()?.key` return `optional` that's why need to **safe unwrap** because of it's might be `nil` so far `avoid crash`

Comment: Thanks for explaining the safe unwrap - makes more sense now!